# How is possible to relate volatility with risk?

Tags: volatility, risk, risk-management

I read that equallying voliatility with risk is one of the hardest critics on Quantitative Finance and that this is -indeed- the fundamental base of Quant. This question is analogous considering that volatility is *not equal* to risk, but you can establish a univocal relation between them.

Comment: This is too general. What volatility and risk are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Volatility (often defined in terms of standard deviation of returns, or in terms of implied volatility from option markets) is indeed one measure of risk, but like any single measure of risk, it is incomplete.

Part of the reason for this is that in financial markets, the returns are not normally distributed but rather have "fat tails."  This means that extreme events happen much more frequently than one might expect if one knew only the standard deviation of the returns (volatility) and if one was assuming a normal distribution for the returns.

During the recent financial crisis, some (non-quant) bankers claimed to be seeing events that were many times larger than a standard deviation, with the implication that they were seeing unbelievably improbable events (for example once per ten thousand year events) based on the probability of observing such an event if returns were normally distributed. This has led people to criticize volatility as a measure of risk.

Another commonly used measure of risk is VaR (Value at Risk), which can be calculated using standard deviation, but which then needs to be very carefully interpreted so as not to assume normally distributed returns.  VaR is usually calculated in more sophisticated ways which include much more information than just the standard deviation.

The risk measure one uses needs to be tailored to the situation at hand: for a given institution, there needs to be an agreed "risk tolerance" which at Board level may be stated in high level terms. Then the Chief Risk Officer and team need to interpret that risk tolerance and create risk measures and limits which target the high level concerns - they also need to set up monitors and ensure that the business activity lines up with these risk measures,and does not break any risk limits, unless agreed with management.

So volatility by itself is not typically sufficient as a risk measure for most purposes.

Comment: I am not sure in what ways VaR uses "much more information" than standard deviation does. (But I fully agree that a single measure is not sufficient for all purposes).

Comment: @Alex-C Yes, it is true that a VaR figure can be highly summarized and may not contain a lot of information. The example I am thinking of would be a long data series, where the risk question of interest is the 99.9th percentile.  One could use volatility filtering to standardize the returns and extract an estimate of the 99.9th percentile VaR using EVT. This VaR figure then has incorporated more information than a single moment of the return distribution.  But strictly speaking, you are right: the VaR information content could be considered just "different" rather than "more."